# PHP Logic - IF not equal too

Tags: php, logic

I have this code, im sure i have wrote it correctly. but its not running the echo function action it. it just returns the error.

```
 if( ($amount != "250") || ($amount != "500") || ($amount != "750") || ($amount != "1000") ){
    $error = "You must enter a amount in a multiple of 250.";
    error($error);
 }elseif( ($amount == "250") || ($amount == "500") || ($amount == "750") || ($amount == "1000") ){
    echo "The logic should display this if i type in 250, 500, 750 or 1000";
    }
```

Comment: `if (($amount % 250) != 0)`

Comment: The $amount can only be 250, 500, 750 or 1000. all other amounts are not allowed

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. You should start with logic. To begin with, `not (not a || not  b) = a && b`. Check this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Comment: remove `()` in your if

Comment: you need to close your if statement with this }

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same using the following. Check this for more information about [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
if (!in_array($amount, array(250, 500, 750, 1000))) {
    $error = "You must enter a amount in a multiple of 250.";
    echo $error;
} else {
    echo 'Nice!';
}
```

Comment: This does not explain what the error is or how this resolves it

Comment: Brilliant that worked a charm, thanks

Comment: @Liam Armour - Please make sure to choose this as the correct answer if it is what you needed, John has taken it upon himself to tell us this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: It's ok with @John Conde (too strict though) but the other downvoter should explain why he downvote..

Comment: @Liam Armour if the answer worked then don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably better to do this:

```
if($amount >= 250 && $amount <= 1000 && ($amount % 250) == 0) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

Your error is in the first if statement:

```
if( ($amount != "250") || ($amount != "500") || ($amount != "750") || ($amount != "1000") ){
```

It should be

```
if( ($amount != "250") && ($amount != "500") && ($amount != "750") && ($amount != "1000") ){
    $error = "You must enter a amount in a multiple of 250.";
    echo "error"; 
}else {
    echo "The logic should display this if i type in 250, 500, 750 or 1000";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just fyi a better way to do this would be:

```
if( $amount % 250 == 0) {
    echo $amount;
} else {
    echo "You must enter a amount in a multiple of 250.";
}
```

Comment: This does not explain what the error is or how this resolves it. Plus they said it can only be those four values. This does not account for that.